# Can a new tag for questions related to IIT-JEE be introduced?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

There are a lot of question on Chemistry, Physics and Mathematics SE that are related to IIT-JEE. For those who don't know it is an Indian examination in which around a million students participate each year. It would be really helpful for JEEaspirants as we will be able to sort through the questions related specifically to IIT-JEE

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I agree that there are a lot of questions related to JEE on this site (I myself asked a lot of them!). However, I disagree that we should create a specific tag for them.

Tags that don't describe the actual content of the question are called meta tags. Meta tags are discouraged on StackExchange for a very long time now, see [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) from 2010. Examples of other meta tags would be [beginner](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) or (drumrolls...) [homework](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework). As per this description, [iit-jee](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iit-jee) would be a meta tag that doesn't describe the actual content of the question.

So, while I do agree such a tag can certainly help JEE aspirants filter questions as per their needs, that tag simply doesn't fit into the SE model.

Comment: If everyone were to include the source of the exercises (a citation for example), then one could easily use the search ([q=JEE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=jee)) to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン But it will show only the questions asked in JEE examination while most of them are from other books and sources that are related to JEE. These   can be easily missed through the search.

Comment: @AdityaJain If there are so many books related to these examinations, then they surely also have a name and could be referenced, and then you could search for these instead.